# Logging object in Blazor to Console

Tags: logging, blazor, blazor-client-side

I'd like to log an object to the console browser for viewing at runtime on a client side WASM Blazor app.

I can log string values no problem but I like to be able to log and drill down on objects as I would using javascript console.log.

I am running;

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor 3.1.0-Preview3.19555.2
Blazor.Extensions.Logging 1.1.0-preview2
```

The documentation for states

> The logger supports the same string formatting that MEL provides, together with named parameter replacement in the message.
>
> Additionaly, you're able to log an object in the browser console. You can expand members and hierachies to see what's contained within.
>
> If you want to log an enumerable list of objects, then the browser side component will display it by calling console.table.

Taken from [BlazorExtensions/Logging](https://github.com/BlazorExtensions/Logging)

However, for example, if I am to run the a log as follows;

```
logger.LogDebug(result);
```

where result is a POCO object. it doesn't compile.

I inject the logger to the `razor` file

```
@inject ILogger<AddForm> logger
```

and in my `startup.cs`

```
services.AddLogging(builder => builder
    .AddBrowserConsole() 
    .SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace)
);
```

and finally in my `_import.razor` I have;

```
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
```

For completeness I have also tried JSON serialising the object;

```
 logger.LogDebug("Logging Contact Object", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(contact));
```

but this is just outputs `object' to the console.

and also;

```
logger.LogDebug($"Logging Contact Object :{contact}:");
```

but this just logs the name of the object.

Can anyone please help direct me as to where I am going wrong here?

Comment: Did you add the script tag to the index.html ? Works here. Cant see what else is different between my config and yours.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a wrapper for javascript console.log in c#.

In your html or javascript file, define a function -

```
log = (obj) => { console.log(obj); }
```

Then in your blazor service file -

```
public async Task LogToConsole(object obj)
{
    await _jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("log", obj); //_jsRuntime is injected IJSRuntime
}
```

Then you can log whatever object to console by calling this method in you blazor page/component.

I tested it in Chrome.

Comment: While this works it's not required but it gave me [some ideas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72974137/237917)

Answer (score 0):

By the time this question was asked, it is probable that the Console API doesn't exist yet. But today, we can do this:

```
Console.WriteLine('my string');
```

That will output in Chrome DevTools' Console panel. Tested in Blazor WebAssembly and .Net 5.0.301 SDK.

Comment: Console.WriteLine is available in previous versions of blazor also. The question here is about logging "object". Console.WriteLine takes string only.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to create adition JS functions when you can use `console.log` directly.

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Calls "console.log" on the client passing the args along with it.
/// </summary>
/// <example>
/// LogAsync("data") //same as console.log('data')
/// </example>
/// <example>
/// LogAsync("data", myData) //same as console.log('data', myData)
/// </example>
/// <param name="js"></param>
/// <param name="args"></param>
public static async Task LogAsync(this IJSRuntime js, params object?[]? args)
{
    await js.InvokeVoidAsync("console.log", args);
}
```

Use as

```cs
[Inject]
private IJSRuntime Js { get; set; } = default!;

await Js.LogAsync(myObject);
```

I wrote a couple of other extensions you can find here:
https://gist.github.com/Eonasdan/9cbd63c7e2ebd8624191a97befb64f00